# Adobe air scrolling optimize (mobile devices)

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a list of displayObject (contains Sprite and Bitmap) to scroll through. It gets about 6,000 height in pixel, and thing just get slow down with performance on the tablet. (iPad1)

Just wondering is there any way or best practice to optimize it. I think Adobe Air really should have a native support for that.

Any suggestions or idea is appreciated.

Cheers
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1.
Set StageQuality to LOW. If you only have an issue with iPad1 you could test for a camera before setting the quality.

```
if (!CameraUI.isSupported) {
stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
}
```

Option 2.
Build your app using Starling and Feathers.
http://feathersui.com